# Get Order Details by Order Id

Tags: orders

I need to retrieve an order in Magento by its Id. How do I load a specific order by Id?

So far I've gotten the initial query constructed:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order');
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To load an order by increment id one would do:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); //use a real increment order id here
```

To load by entity id you would just call `load`:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); //use an entity id here
```

Comment: i test it by order id and increment id but it`s show me no thing and no error ! http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39762/get-order-details-by-order-id-in-magento

Comment: That's what I needed

Answer (score 17):

Getting the Order Details depends on a few components:

1. The Order (normally order #)
2. The Contents of the Order (Simple vs Configurable, Invisible etc.)
3. The Information you're looking to Extract (Pricing vs Other information)

Load your Order: (db: sales_flat_order)

```
$OrderNumber = "100000001";//Put your order Number here
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber, 'increment_id');
```

Next, Filter your Collection of Items based on the Order.

What most will do is: (db: sales_flat_order_item)

```
$order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Which will show the visible products. The problem with this is, that it will get the "configurable" item from the collection (which strangely has the child's sku in the record). I find this to be unpredictable in the case of SKU changes as the historical SKU is no longer present. Instead, I find it better to do an alternative approach as follows.

```
 $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
        ->load();
```

- getItemsCollection() will actually return the Parent and the Child, confusing for most. Lets focus on the child.
- Traditionally, the Parent (ie.Configurable) will have the pricing information, where the child (simple) will not. 
  With the Child (simple product) we're able to determine if there is a parent_id (but not the reverse) and we're able to also grab product information from entity_id (not the reverse) as  from getAllVisibleItems().
- iterate through the collection of order items

  ```
  foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {

      //Ignore conf for now
      //Alt. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE = 'simple';
      if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
      {



          echo "\n*********************************\nMage Order #: ".$OrderNumber."\n";
          //Simple Item Info from Order
          echo "Type: ".$sItem->getProductType()."\n";
          echo "Order Id: ".$sItem->getOrderId()."\n";
          echo "Product Id: ".$sItem->getProductId()."\n";
          echo "Item Id: ".$sItem->getId()."\n";
          echo "Item Name: ".$sItem->getName()."\n";
          echo "Item Sku: ".$sItem->getSku()."\n";
          echo "Item Price: ".$sItem->getPrice()."\n";

          $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();
          echo "Parent Item Id: ".$pItemId."\n";

          echo "\n*****\n";
  //Get Parent Item Information
  $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId"); //use an item_id here

          //Testing, want to see whats inside the parent/configurable item?
          //print_r($item->toArray());

          echo "Parent Type: ".$item->getProductType()."\n";
          echo "Parent Order Id: ".$item->getOrderId()."\n";
          echo "Product Id: ".$item->getProductId()."\n";
          echo "Item Id: ".$item->getId()."\n";
          echo "Parent Item Price: ".$item->getPrice()."\n";
          echo "Qty: ".$qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered())."\n";

          //get Active Product Data
          $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
  $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();
      echo "new Product UPC:".$nUpc = $nProduct->getUpc() . "\n";
          echo "new Product Price:".$nPrice = $nProduct->getPrice(). "\n";

          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Just a note, you ```intval``` the ```getQtyOrdered```, but that can be a decimal value :)

Comment: Where I can find all the documentation about model built-in function like `addAttributeToSelect`. Thank you.